# como criar uma função que tem três parâmetros, mas só utilizo dois de cada desses parâmetros em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso criar uma função, que calcule as razões trigonométricas existentes entre os lados de um
triângulo retângulo.
A função deve receber três parâmetros: cateto oposto, cateto adjacente
e hipotenusa. Ao executar a função, apenas dois dos três parâmetros devem receber valores.
A função vai retornar o valor referente ao Seno, Cosseno ou Tangente de acordo com os
valores recebidos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer utilizando um dos parâmetros sendo zero, e fazer uma condição para retornar o resultado baseando-se em qual parâmetro se iguala a zero.

```
def calcularTriangulo(catetoOp,catetoAdj,hipotenusa):
if (catetoOp == 0):
    # retorna Cosseno
    print(catetoAdj/hipotenusa)
elif (catetoAdj == 0):
    # retorna Seno
    print(catetoOp/hipotenusa)
elif (hipotenusa == 0):
    # retorna Tangente
    print(catetoOp/catetoAdj)
```

Assim por exemplo, para calcular a tangente seria:

calcularTriangulo(3,4,0) *-- Tangente*

Mesma coisa para Seno e Cosseno:

calcularTriangulo(0,4,5) *-- Cosseno*

calcularTriangulo(3,0,5) *-- Seno*

Comment: Obrigado! Logo no inicio o texto era quase um paradoxo, mas depois eu entendi como funcionava, encontrei a resposta. mas obrigado pela boa itenção